# how to adjust a video according to a specific size?

Tags: css, html, html5-video

I'm trying to insert a background looping video at the top of the page. (Not the whole page. Just the upper portion of it like a cover video.)But i can't get it to fit the window properly.

**html code**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

        <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title> </title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles.css" type="text/css">
        </head>

        <body>

        <nav>
        <div>
        <ul>
         <li  id="logo"> <img src="logo.JPEG" width="100" height="25"> </li>
         <li> <a href="index.html" class="active">  Home  </a> </li>
         <li> <a href="#"> Categories </a> </li>
         <li> <a href="#"> Quiz </a> </li>
         <li> <a href="#"> Buy Products </a> </li>
         <li> <a href="#"> Our Details </a> </li>
         </ul>
        </div>
        </nav>

        <video autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
```

**css code**

```
    body {
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #111110  ;
    }

    nav{
      text-align: right;
      background-color: black;
      top: 0;
      overflow:hidden; 
    }

    nav ul li {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    a {
      padding:15px;
      font-family: "Open Sans";
      text-transform:uppercase;
      color: white;
      font-size: 15px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    a:hover {
      background: yellow;
      color: black;
    }

    .active{
        background-color:#B3B6B7;
    }

    #logo{
        float: left;
    }

    video{
      width:70%;
      transform: translate(0%,0%);
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

This is the code I've got so far. Can someone tell me how to get this video adjusted properly.The height I've given for this video is right but i'm having trouble stretching it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the video HTML attribute without any CSS:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_height.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`<video width="320" height="240" controls poster="/video/wind-8a1cd93f.png" id="styled_video" muted preload="metadata" loop>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>`

You can also style the video element styled_video.

Hope this helps answer your question

Comment: This isn't what i need...what i need is a background looping cover video...